# Compare columnA to columnB and get percentage of specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this and i would like to calculate the percentage of the columnB comparing to columnA. In this example in columnB i have 3 values which are identic to the values of columnA

```
   columnA   columnB 
0  A         None    
1  H         H           <---
2  A         A           <---
3  H         H           <---
4  A         H
```

expected result:

```
   columnB 
0  75%
```

stay healthy!

EDIT: I just noticed that in my use case, i want to ignore rows which contain the 'None' value. I want the result to be 75 or 75%.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the exact output in that format use:

```
new_df = df.replace({'None': None}).dropna()
result = (
    new_df[['columnB']].eq(new_df['columnA'], axis=0)
        .mean().mul(100)
        .to_frame().T.applymap('{:.0f}%'.format)
)
```

Assuming the None values are already the python `None` or `NaN, and not the string` 'None'` use:

```
new_df = df.dropna()
result = (
    new_df[['columnB']].eq(new_df['columnA'], axis=0)
        .mean().mul(100)
        .to_frame().T.applymap('{:.0f}%'.format)
)
```

`result`:

```
  columnB
0     75%
```

---

Assuming just the values would do use:

```
new_df = df.replace({'None': None}).dropna()
result = new_df['columnB'].eq(new_df['columnA']).mean() * 100
```

```
75.0
```

---

Complete Working Example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'columnA': ['A', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'A'],
                   'columnB': ['None', 'H', 'A', 'H', 'H']})

new_df = df.replace({'None': None}).dropna()
result = (
    new_df[['columnB']].eq(new_df['columnA'], axis=0)
        .mean().mul(100)
        .to_frame().T.applymap('{:.0f}%'.format)
)

print(result)
```

Comment: Your solution fits perfectly in my use case. tank you sir!

Comment: excuse me, I just noticed that in my use case, i want to ignore rows which contain the 'None' value. I want the result to be 75 or 75%.

Could you give me hint?

Comment: If they are `None` like the python value you could do `df = df.dropna()` before running this code. If it's the string `"None"` you could replace `"None"` with `None` then drop `df = df.replace({'None': None}).dropna()`. Please see the edits.

Answer (score 2):

To get a percentage:

```py
perc = df["columnA"].eq(df["columnB"]).sum() / len(df) * 100
print(perc)
```

Prints:

```
60.0
```

---

As a dataframe:

```py
df_out = pd.DataFrame(
    {"ColumnB": [df["columnA"].eq(df["columnB"]).sum() / len(df) * 100]}
)
print(df_out)
```

Prints:

```
   ColumnB
0     60.0
```